# EthereumPool - what withdrawal means

Tags: ethminer

I am mining for the first time in my life, and doing it so in the last 24 hours.

I am running this command :  `ethminer -G -F http://ethereumpool.co/?miner=17@0x44a7709d896dc619391423b902a9570b9f3ba90d`

so I am using ethminer, and ethereumpool. I can see a valid hashrate and all seem to be working in my terminal.

But EthereumPool mentions that withdrawals happen only after a certain threshold :

```
When i will receive withdraw?
When your balance exceed 1 ether. Withdraws are processed once a day.
```

Until I reach the 1 ether which might take months with my hashing power, can I check my pending balance somehow so that I make sure I am mining correctly?

Or should I choose another pool? I am just worried I might be mining for months and then realize I did something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the statistics for any miner contributing to the pool by looking at the miner stats tab.

For the address you posted you can see the stats here for example:

https://ethereumpool.co/stats/miner/index.php?address=0x44a7709d896dc619391423b902a9570b9f3ba90d